# How to insert a JSON Array into Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I look for examples to solve my problem but im confused.
If Ii have a json array like this:

```
$json = '{"a":"test","b":"test2"},{"a":"test3","b":"test4"}';

//decode to get as php variable
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

My problem is when i try to insert the values in the database

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO suspiciousactivity (ID,Notes)
VALUES ('".$obj->{'a'}."','".$obj->{'b'}."')")or die(mysql_error());
```

I get this error: `duplicate entry for key PRIMARY`

How can I insert a multiple values from my `JsonArray` to my database?

Comment: Seems to me like you already have a `suspiciousactivity ` entry with ID = test

Comment: So, you're using results from suspicious activity, and insert it into your database without sanitising? Please change your code, stop using mysql_ functions. They are deprecated and no longer maintained. Your code is very insecure and vulnerable for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use:

```
$json = '{"a":"test","b":"test2"},{"a":"test3","b":"test4"}';

//decode to get as php variable
$arr = json_decode($json,true); //true to decode as a array not an object

mysql_query("INSERT INTO suspiciousactivity (ID,Notes)
VALUES ('".$arr[0]['a']."','".$arr[0]['b']."')")or die(mysql_error());
//use it as an array.
```

Comment: sorry, try now. I have changed ´$obj´ for ´$arr´

Comment: i try but echo $arr[0]['a']; is empty

Comment: sorry i was missin the [] in the $json thanks it works for me