# Inset php json encoded array into database

Tags: php, sql, json, decode, encode

I need to insert elements of a php encoded array into a database and I'm completely stuck. I have first used json encode to to grab data from the database using an SQL query (which I did successfully) but I now need to be able to do the opposite. If anyone could help I'd greatly appreciate it. It's my second day of work and I'm not doing so well. The following is my code:

```
    $UserCoords_Query  = "Select Accuracy, Longitude, Latitude, Timestamp                            
        FROM UserDetails
          WHERE UserId =" . $UserID;
                  $UserCoords_result = mysql_query($UserCoords_Query);

if (mysql_num_rows($UserCoords_result) == 0) {
    echo "There are no users with an id of ". $UserID;
}

else {
            $EmptyArray=array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($UserCoords_result)) {
        $Accuracy=$row['Accuracy'];
        $Longitude= $row['Longitude'];
        $Latitude=$row['Latitude'];
        $Timestamp= $row['Timestamp'];

        $Queue= array('Accuracy:' => $Accuracy, 'Latitude' => $Latitude, 'Longitude' => $Longitude, 'Timestamp' => $Timestamp); 
        array_unshift($EmptyArray,$Queue);
}   

    $ObjectResponse = array('Coords' => $EmptyArray);
    echo json_encode($ObjectResponse);

    $Json_Encoded= json_encode($ObjectResponse);

   $Json_Decoded= json_decode($Json_Encoded, true);

    $Update_Query= "INSERT INTO UserDetails (UserId, Accuracy, Latitude, Longitude,         Timestamp)
    VALUES ('".$UserID."','".$Json_Decoded[0]        ['Accuracy']."','".$Json_Decoded[0]['Latitude']."',
    '".$Json_Decoded[0]['Longitude']."','".$Json_Decoded[0]['Timestamp']."')";

    mysql_query($Update_Query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: you shouldn't be inserting json text into a db, unless you plan to NEVER access any individual sub-data from the json text with sql. json's a transport format, not a storage format.

Comment: @ Marc B Well I'd need to explode the string to get the elements and add them to the DB. I thought that was what the json decode function does?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with chandresh_cool. you should use 'true' option to decode the json encoded string as array, otherwise it will return an object.

moreover, [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) expects a filename (with full or relative path). When you try to give a json_encoded string, it thinks that its the file name and it will try to open it as a file, which, obviously does not exist, and thus throws an error. Try to give an existing filename and see that solves the problem.

P.s. I know this should be a comment, but due to insufficient points, I cannot comment

Comment: @ dhavald I have edited the code to include the true option and removed the file get contents function. However, I am still receiving the error:Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/roseanne/public_html/display_Coords.php on line 26

Comment: No because the query involves using variables from the decoded array but I have some mistake involving that decode.

Comment: @ dhavald If it helps, I was using the following link as a guideline. But it didn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736880/how-to-insert-a-json-array-into-mysql

Comment: @  dhavald That produces this??:                               array(1) { ["Coords"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["Accuracy"]=> string(2) "56" ["Latitude"]=> string(2) "78" ["Longitude"]=> string(2) "89" ["Timestamp"]=> string(3) "909" } [1]=> array(4) { ["Accuracy"]=> string(2) "56" ["Latitude"]=> string(2) "78" ["Longitude"]=> string(2) "89" ["Timestamp"]=> string(3) "909" } } }

Comment: @ dhavald Do you know how I could access these elements? In my query I'm using $Json_Decoded[0]['Accuracy'] etc., but that obviously isn't working

Comment: $Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Accuracy'], $Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Latitude'] etc

Comment: I updated the query to the following, but it still isn't updating the database :/ Thanks for all your help btw, Much appreciated: $Update_Query= "INSERT INTO UserDetails (UserId, Accuracy, Latitude, Longitude, Timestamp)
  VALUES ('34','".$Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Accuracy']."','".$Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Latitude']."',
'".$Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Longitude']."','".$Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Timestamp']."')";

Comment: echoing $Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Accuracy'] etc, does produce the right values but they aren't updating the DB. Can you see the error in the query? It would be so good to get this done before tomorrow. I had never heard of json before today so I'm a complete noob!

Comment: try removing extra quotes from query: '34','.$Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]['Accuracy'].','.$Json_Decoded['Coords'][0]‌​['Latitude'].', ... If this does not solve, remove die() add a try catch around mysql_query and post Exception Message here.

Comment: @ dhavald hmmm that's giving an error of Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/roseanne/public_html/display_Coords.php on line 72.   Line 72 is the line with the update query

Comment: can you dump $Update_Query

Comment: @ dhavald as in: echo var_dump($Update_Query); that didn't display anything on screen when I added in that line :/

Comment: just var_dump(), nothing else

Comment: @ dhavald var_dump($Update_Query) isn't returning anything on screen either

Answer (score 0):

You need to set second parameter of json_encode as true to return array

```
$Json_Decoded = json_decode($Json_Encoded, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. However, I'm still getting an error of   "Warning: file_get_contents({"Coords":[{"Accuracy:":"56","Latitude":"78","Longitude":"89","Timestamp":"909"}]}): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/roseanne/public_html/display_Coords.php on line 48"

Comment: @ chandresh_cool this is the only error I get. Line 48 is this line: $Json_Data = file_get_contents($Json_Encoded);